# Java: Replacing String with Integer

Tags: java, string, replace, hashmap, integer

I'm new here, so I hope I can describe this problem right, as well as help others when I'm more into Java and stuff.

But here's why I'm here...I need to convert a given text-file, so I can use it in a program called "SUBDUE".

The format of the given graphs in the file looks like this:

```
v 2_i_6 startevent

v 2_i_7 endevent

v 2_i_1 task
v 2_i_2 task
v 2_i_3 task
v 2_i_4 task
v 2_i_5 task

v 2_i_15 and
v 2_i_17 and
v 2_i_14 xor
v 2_i_16 xor
v 2_i_18 xor
v 2_i_19 xor
```

But for the program, the graphs in this file need to look like this:

```
v 1 startevent

v 2 endevent

v 3 task
v 4 task
v 5 task
v 6 task
v 7 task

v 8 and
v 9 and
v 10 xor
v 11 xor
v 12 xor
v 13 xor
```

At first I thought that I'll do it by hand. But I realized that there are 2000 of them. So I tried to write a program in Java.

So here is what I got:

```
public class Input {

HashMap<String, Integer> replacements = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public void readFile() throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(
            "file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.startsWith("%")) {//every graph starts with % and a number so i know which graph is currently in progress
            i = 0;
        }
        if (line.startsWith("v")) {
            i++;
            replacements.put(line.split(" ")[1], i);
        }
    }
    fr.close();

    fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> e : replacements.entrySet()) {
            line = line.replaceAll(e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue().toString());
            line.toString();
        }
        sb.append(line);
        System.out.println(line);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    fr.close();

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(
            new File("file.txt"));
    fw.write(sb.toString());
    fw.close();
}
```

When I start the program, it converts mostly right, but sometimes this happens:

```
v 1 startevent

v 2 endevent

v 3 task
v 4 task
v 5 task
v 6 task
v 7 task

v 35 and
v 37 and
v 34 xor
v 36 xor
v 38 xor
v 39 xor
```

I started debugging, but gave up, because I needed to go through the whole Map, until the right key was found.. So I deleted `i++` in the first `while-loop`, so `i` was `0` all the time. And got something like this:

```
v 0 startevent

v 0 endevent

v 0 task
v 0 task
v 0 task
v 0 task
v 0 task

v 05 and
v 07 and
v 04 xor
v 06 xor
v 08 xor
v 09 xor
```

But I don't know why it only replaced the first number of the double-digit ones.

I hope someone has a hint for me, or an even better option to replace these strings how I want it to.

Thank you for your answers.

Because requested here are the first three graphs of my file. Sorry for the inconvinience,

```
%1./konvertiermich/andere/Paper-Leben-Modeliranje_delovnih_procesov/obdelava_narocil.epml.pl

v 1_i_2 startevent

v 1_i_17 endevent
v 1_i_23 endevent
v 1_i_26 endevent

v 1_i_4 task
v 1_i_5 task
v 1_i_9 task
v 1_i_11 task
v 1_i_20 task
v 1_i_21 task
v 1_i_25 task

v 1_i_6 xor
v 1_i_10 xor
v 1_i_13 xor
v 1_i_14 xor
v 1_i_15 xor
v 1_i_19 xor
v 1_i_22 xor

d 1_i_2 1_i_4 arc
d 1_i_5 1_i_6 arc
d 1_i_9 1_i_10 arc
d 1_i_10 1_i_14 arc
d 1_i_10 1_i_15 arc
d 1_i_11 1_i_13 arc
d 1_i_13 1_i_14 arc
d 1_i_13 1_i_15 arc
d 1_i_20 1_i_17 arc
d 1_i_19 1_i_21 arc
d 1_i_21 1_i_22 arc
d 1_i_22 1_i_23 arc
d 1_i_25 1_i_26 arc
d 1_i_4 1_i_5 arc
d 1_i_6 1_i_9 arc
d 1_i_6 1_i_19 arc
d 1_i_10 1_i_11 arc
d 1_i_15 1_i_20 arc
d 1_i_14 1_i_19 arc
d 1_i_22 1_i_25 arc

%2./konvertiermich/andere/Web-Wikipedia.cz/wikipedia.cz.epml.pl

v 2_i_6 startevent

v 2_i_7 endevent

v 2_i_1 task
v 2_i_2 task
v 2_i_3 task
v 2_i_4 task
v 2_i_5 task

v 2_i_15 and
v 2_i_17 and
v 2_i_14 xor
v 2_i_16 xor
v 2_i_18 xor
v 2_i_19 xor

d 2_i_1 2_i_14 arc
d 2_i_3 2_i_18 arc
d 2_i_6 2_i_3 arc
d 2_i_14 2_i_7 arc
d 2_i_15 2_i_5 arc
d 2_i_16 2_i_1 arc
d 2_i_17 2_i_4 arc
d 2_i_17 2_i_2 arc
d 2_i_19 2_i_17 arc
d 2_i_2 2_i_15 arc
d 2_i_4 2_i_15 arc
d 2_i_18 2_i_19 arc
d 2_i_5 2_i_16 arc
d 2_i_14 2_i_19 arc
d 2_i_18 2_i_16 arc

%3./konvertiermich/deutsch/BA-Blau-Customer_Relationship_Management_gestützte_Prozesse_am_Beispiel_des_Unternehmens_Alere/39-Angebotsprozess.pl

v 3_i_1 startevent

v 3_i_19 endevent

v 3_i_2 task
v 3_i_6 task
v 3_i_7 task
v 3_i_10 task
v 3_i_13 task
v 3_i_15 task
v 3_i_18 task

v 3_i_3 xor
v 3_i_8 xor
v 3_i_12 xor
v 3_i_17 xor

d 3_i_1 3_i_2 arc
d 3_i_2 3_i_3 arc
d 3_i_6 3_i_8 arc
d 3_i_7 3_i_8 arc
d 3_i_12 3_i_13 arc
d 3_i_17 3_i_18 arc
d 3_i_18 3_i_19 arc
d 3_i_12 3_i_17 arc
d 3_i_3 3_i_6 arc
d 3_i_3 3_i_7 arc
d 3_i_8 3_i_10 arc
d 3_i_10 3_i_12 arc
d 3_i_13 3_i_15 arc
d 3_i_15 3_i_17 arc
```

Comment: You have `if (line.startsWith("%")) {//every graph starts with % and a number so i know which graph is currently in progress` but you don't have `%` anywhere in your input.

Comment: the problem is there are 2000 graphs like this. graph 3 f.e. got `3_i_`, graph 4  `4_i_` and so on. also the numbers need to be in correct order from 1 to how many there will be. i tried with an editor, but it will take too long.

Comment: Can you include a more complete example because at the moment it just looks like the middle column is a counter? I suspect the is no need to read the file more than once.

Comment: in my file every graph starts with something like `%x`. the difference is that x stands for a number fom 1 to 2000. forgot to insert it, i'm sorry. ._.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I edited my post, so at the end you can see the first 3 complete graphs. will this work?

Comment: If one of the answers is correct you should check it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be used as a starting point. Splitting the string seems to be a better approach.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String [] input = {"v 2_i_6 startevent", "", "v 2_i_7 endevent"};

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(myStringFormatter(input[i]));
    }
}

static String myStringFormatter(String input)
{
    if(input.length() > 0)
    {
        String[] processing = input.split(" ");//Splits the string  into 3 parts v, 2_i_6, and startevent
        String[] processing2 = processing[1].split("_");//Splits 2_i_6 into 3 parts 2, i, and 6

        return processing[0] + " " + processing2[2] + " " + processing[2]; //Takes the first part of the first split, the third part of the second split, and the third part of the first split and put them back together separated by a space
    }

    return "";//If it gets an empty string, its going to return an empty string
}
```

> Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I add this part to your code

```
ArrayList <String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
int counter=0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("%")) {//every graph starts with % and a number so i know which graph is currently in progress
            i = 0;
        }
        if (line.startsWith("v")) {
            i++;
            counter++;
            strings.add(line.split(" ")[0]+" "+counter+" "+line.split(" ")[2]);
            replacements.put(line.split(" ")[1], counter);
        }
    }
fr.close();
strings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

as you can see I add a `counter` ans a arrayList named `stirngs` and just before your replacement hash map I did collect first and last part of the string instead of taking the middle part as you did and print in `strings.forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 0):

your replace all logic is incorrect.

3_i_1 maps to 3

it also match the replaceAll case for 3_i_15 which is why you see it being replaced as 34, 35, 36

I had two graphs in my file.txt and I see the problem manifest with the second graph. One workaround is to append a " " space in the replace all clause to distinguish between 3_i_1 versus 3_i_15

Since you are iterating over the entries of your hashmap, looks like 2_i_15, 8 appears before 2_i_1,3 whereas 3_i_1,3 appears before 3_i_15,8.